# Move element from front of array to back of array in R

Tags: r

Is there an elegant way to take a vector like

```
x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

and make it be

```
x = c("b", "c", "d", "e", "a")
```

I did:

```
x = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
firstVal = x[1]
x = tail(x,-1)
x[length(x)+1] = firstVal
x
[1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "a"
```

It works, but kinda ugly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Elegance is a matter of taste, and *de gustibus non est disputandum*:

```
> x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
> c(x[-1], x[1])
[1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "a"
```

Does the above make you happy? :)

Comment: Oooo that is very elegant indeed. Thanks.

Comment: This question made my day! :)

Comment: @user244034, [relevant reading](http://news.mrdwab.com/2012/12/04/what-exactly-is-elegant-code-in-r/) (shameless plug) :-)

Comment: Only questions that make your day are worth asking

Comment: Be glad that this hasn't been closed as a "primarily opinion-based question" :P

Comment: To [add to the enjoyment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23370870/1270695)... (hopefully)

Comment: Extension to this if you would like to specify the specific string would be: `c(x[-which(x == "a")], "a"])`

Answer (score 7):

Overkill time: You can consider my **[`shifter`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/shifter.R)** or my **[`moveMe`](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/moveMe.R)** function, both of which are part of my GitHub-only **[SOfun](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun)** package.

Here are the relevant examples:

#### `shifter`

This is basically a `head` and `tail` approach:

```
## Specify how many values need to be shifted
shifter(x, 1)
# [1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "a"
shifter(x, 2)
# [1] "c" "d" "e" "a" "b"

## The direction can be changed too :-)
shifter(x, -1)
# [1] "e" "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

#### `moveMe`

This is fun:

```
moveMe(x, "a last")
# [1] "b" "c" "d" "e" "a"

## Lots of options to move things around :-)
moveMe(x, "a after d; c first")
# [1] "c" "b" "d" "a" "e"
```

Comment: `beauty(shifter(x, 1)) == 87`, but not including `install_github` call :)

Answer (score 4):

Agreed with the matter of taste comment. My personal approach would be:

```
x[c(2:length(x), 1)]
```

Comment: By applying the following measure of *beauty*: `beauty <- function(x) max(0, 100-nchar(deparse(substitute(x))))`, we have `beauty(c(x[-1], x[1])) == 86` vs `beauty(x[2:length(x), 1]) == 83` :P

Comment: I think `c` is naturally inelegant, but `beauty(x[seq(along=x) %% length(x) + 1])` is only 68 ;)

Comment: Well, user244034's solution has score of 29 (after applying `paste` in `beauty()`), so he's unbeatable :)

Answer (score 3):

I had an idea to use both `head` and `tail` that turned out to be a flop when I benchmarked.

```
c(tail(x, -1), head(x, 1))
```

I figured I'd share the results as they're informative.  I also scaled up for larger vectors and the results were interesting:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")  

gagolews <- function() c(x[-1], x[1])

senoro <- function() x[c(2:length(x), 1)]

tyler <- function() c(tail(x, -1), head(x, 1))

ananda <- function() shifter(x, 1)

user <-function(){
   firstVal = x[1]
   x = tail(x,-1)
   x[length(x)+1] = firstVal
   x
}


library(microbenchmark)
(op <- microbenchmark( 
    gagolews(),
    senoro(),
    tyler(),
    ananda(),
    user(),
times=100L))

## Unit: microseconds
##        expr    min     lq median     uq      max neval
##  gagolews()  1.400  1.867  2.333  2.799    5.132  1000
##    senoro()  1.400  1.867  2.333  2.334   10.730  1000
##     tyler() 37.320 39.187 40.120 41.519  135.287  1000
##    ananda() 39.653 41.519 42.452 43.386   69.043  1000
##      user() 24.259 25.658 26.591 27.058 1757.789  1000
```

[image]
Here I scaled up.  I only benched on 100 replications because of the size of the vector (1 million characters).

```
x <- rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 1000000)

## Unit: milliseconds
##        expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
##  gagolews() 168.9151 171.3631 179.0490 193.9604 260.5963   100
##    senoro() 192.2669 203.9596 259.1366 272.5570 341.4443   100
##     tyler() 237.4218 246.5368 303.5700 319.3999 347.3610   100
##    ananda() 237.9610 247.2097 303.9898 318.4564 342.2518   100
##      user() 225.4503 234.3431 287.8348 300.8078 319.2051   100
```

[image]

Comment: And in this way you've introduced the second measure of beauty to our discussion :)

Comment: `shifter` and `c(tail(x, -1), head(x, 1))` are one and the same, and those milliseconds of waiting are *killing* me :-)

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that could potentially be improved with the previous answers is that you have to know the location number of the item you want to move, which in longer vectors could become an issue. You could instead do something like:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
new_x <- c(x[-which(x == "a")], "a")
```